# how to populate existing list / array

Tags: ocaml, reason

I am new at reason / ocaml / functional programming.

I know about `List.append` and `[] @ []` but these functions will create new list but how to populate existing list / array?

1. What is the best way to populate list?
2. What is the best way to populate array? Means if coords type is `let coords: array point = [];`
3. Or this is wrong flow (algorithm) for such case?

Reason code:

```
type point = {x: int, y: int};

let coords: list point = [];

let append raw =>
  Array.iter
    (
      fun data => {
        let p = {x: data.x, y: data.y};
        /* how to append p to coords */
        ()
      }
    )
    raw;
```

JS analogue:

```
const coords = [];
const append = raw => raw.forEach({x, y} => {
  coords.push({
    x: process(x),
    y: process(y)
  });
});
```

Comment: The annoyingly simple answer: in FP you don't need a separate `coords`, since it's an exact copy of `raw`. Just keep using raw.

Comment: @Yawar I have updates code. For example - coords contains processed x y (means that not exact copy)

Comment: See Cheng Lou's answer, it's comprehensive, but in short you'd do something like `List.map (fun {x, y} => {x: process x, y: process y}) raw`

Comment: yeas, `List.map` will help but scopes (where list was created and where list should be mapped) are different

Comment: I don't understand, can you provide an example of the scope problem?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tuchk4/7130405338a41a7a91b6de22356c072e

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to Reason!

In Reason/OCaml, lists are immutable. Under the hood they're simple singly-linked list. You create new ones each time you "modify" them. Here's an example:

```
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = [0, ...a];
```

This is akin to JavaScript's array "spread", except here you're taking the existing `a`, linking a new node `0` at the front, and calling it b. `a` still points to `[1, 2, 3]` (thus "immutable"). `b` is now `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. This is efficient since the `[1, 2, 3]` part is shared.

The advantage of this is that you don't have to worry about passing your list around and accidentally have an obscure function modify it. List's immutability allows you to reason about your code purely by looking at the value you're staring right now (since it'll never change!).

The drawback of list is that it's inefficient to add something at the end:

```
let c = a @ [4]
```

That operation's basically taking a list of one item, `[4]`, and successively attaching each item of `[1, 2, 3]` to it. So linear in terms of perf. But judging by the simplicity of the list implementation, it was historically deemed worth the tradeoff.

So 3. it's the wrong flow if you're trying to set a list item.

1. The best way to populate a list in your case is by mapping over it non-mutatively, from the old list: `let newList = List.map (fun blabla => ...) raw`
2. Same for array. Map over it. There's `Array.of_list` and `Array.to_list` if you're ever stuck.

More on array: OCaml array is mutable, and its size is unchangeable. Think of it as a block of memory. You'd allocate a new array through `Array.make newSize`, then populate it through `Array.set`. This wouldn't make sense if you're resizing the array a lot, so choose the right data structure.

For JS compilation, BuckleScript compiles an ocaml array to a JS array. It's thus mutable *and* resizable. You'll find your familiar JS array operations under [`Js.Array`](http://bloomberg.github.io/bucklescript/api/Js.Array.html)

As a general heuristic, if you'd like to change the length: try `filter`. If you'd like to change the length and the contained items, try `fold_left`. Otherwise, `map`.

More recently, we've started implementing some immutable, resizable, optionally mutable array. Stay tuned!

Comment: `List.map (fun blabla => ...) raw`  - but in this case result should be assigned to new variable and according to provided example - scopes (where list was created, and where list should be mapped) are different. So such flow is not correct according to FP flow?

Comment: Yeah I it's assigned to a new variable. I've added a clarification. Btw if you don't use the return value, the type system will warn you. So all's good.

Comment: With `Js.Array` all is ok but I want to use as much as possible reason flow and structure. How to be with this case https://gist.github.com/tuchk4/7130405338a41a7a91b6de22356c072e  The main problem I think  that I don't know how to work with FP :)

Comment: @tuchk4 commented on your gist

Comment: Thanks. Now it is much  more clear for me. Could you please check this case: https://gist.github.com/tuchk4/42a98693fd0d664eea04bd54ad95549e

Comment: I've updated the answer to include info on `filter` and `fold_left`, two things you'd likely use to "map" to a result of different length.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few different ways to do it. If you want to stick with `Js.Array` as you noted in the comments, you can do it like this:

### Using [`Js.Array`](https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/api/js/array) and [`Array.iter`](https://reasonml.github.io/api/Array.html)

```
    type point = {
      x: int,
      y: int,
    };

    let points: array(point) = [|{x: 2, y: 4}|];

    let rawArray = [|[|1, 2|], [|3, 4|], [|9, 4|]|];

    let append = raw => {
      Array.iter(
        a => {
          let data: point = {x: a[0], y: a[1]};
          Js.Array.push(data, points)->ignore;
        },
        raw,
      );
    };

    append(rawArray);

    Js.log2("new points", points);
```

```
...or with tuples with `Js.Array`
```

```
    let rawTuples = [|(3, 5), (4, 9), (9, 4)|];

    append(rawTuples);

    Js.log2("new points", points);
[ { x: 2, y: 4 }, { x: 3, y: 5 }, { x: 4, y: 9 }, { x: 9, y: 4 } ]
```

If you want to do it with `Array.fold_left` and `Array.append` as suggested by @chenglou, you can  try it with

```
        rawArray|>Array.fold_left((a, b) =>
        Array.append(a,  [|{x: b[0], y: b[1]}|]), [||]);
```

It might be cleaner with some helper functions like:

```
    let concatMap = f =>
      Array.fold_left((a, b) => Array.append(a, f(b)), [||]);

    let newPoint = coord => [|{x: coord[0], y: coord[1]}|];
```

Then calling:

```
    let rawTuples = [|(3, 5), (4, 9), (9, 4)|];

    let arrayTuples = rawTuples |> concatMap(a => [|{x: fst(a), y: snd(a)}|]);
```

Using helpers is also helpful for my understanding of what each part of the function is doing.

Works with `tuples` too since those are just arrays in ReasonML/Ocaml/Rescript

```
    let rawTuples = [|(3, 5), (4, 9), (9, 4)|];

    let arrayTuples = rawTuples |> concatMap(a => [|{x: fst(a), y: snd(a)}|]);
```

### Using [Mutable Records](https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/record#mutable-update)

You have the option of creating your array with `mutable records` .

This is what update an array of mutable records. It not much different.

Here we are using a function to alter the data in the array.

```
    let printCoords = coords => Array.iter(Js.log, coords);

    type mutablePoint('a, 'b) = {
      mutable x: 'a,
      mutable y: 'b,
    };

    let data1: mutablePoint(int, int) = {x: 2, y: 4};

    let data2: mutablePoint(int, int) = {x: 3, y: 4};

    let data3: mutablePoint(int, int) = {x: 4, y: 4};

    let isEven = n => {
      n mod 2 == 0;
    };

    let multiplyByY = data => data.x = data.x * data.y;

    let makeItOdd = data => data.x = data.x + 1;

    let updateData = data => data.x->isEven
       ? data->makeItOdd :  multiplyByY(data);

    let points: array(mutablePoint('x, 'y)) = [|data1, data2, data3|];

    let append = (fn, data) => {
      Array.iter(x => {fn(x)}, data);

      data;
    };

    points |> append(updateData);

    Js.log("points after");

    printCoords(points);

    // points after { x: 3, y: 4 } { x: 12, y: 4 }{ x: 5, y: 4 }
```

Your question was about updating from some raw data so here is an example of that where we are taking the rawdata at index i and using it to change the `x` value on the mutable array:

```
    let points2: array(mutablePoint('x, 'y)) = [|data1, data2, data3|];

    let printCoords = coords => Array.iter(Js.log, coords);

    printCoords(points2);

    let rawData = [|[|1, 2|], [|3, 4|], [|9, 4|]|];

    let update_x_on_point_i = (i, x) => points2[i].x = x;

    let append = raw =>
      Array.iteri(
        (i, d) => {
          let x: int = d[0];

          update_x_on_point_i(i, x);

        },
        raw,
      );

    append(rawData);

    Js.log2("points2 after: ", points2);

    printCoords(points2);

    // points2 after:  [ { x: 1, y: 4 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }, { x: 9, y: 4 } ]
```

These two array happen to be the same size so there is no exception but there will easily be one once the array lengths are different so we should handle that in real life.

### JS Analogue with [`Belt.Array`](https://rescript-lang.org/docs/manual/latest/api/belt/array#mapwithindex)

Just because I happen to have done this today for the same reasons that led me to this post, here is the `JS Analogue` version.

```
    type point = {
      x: int,
      y: int,
    };
    let coords = [|{x: 9, y: 7}, {x: 2, y: 4}, {x: 3, y: 8}|];

    Js.log("coords before");

    Js.log("-------");

    let append = raw =>
      raw->Belt.Array.mapWithIndex(
             _,
             (i, r) => {
               let new_point_i = {x: r[0], y: r[1]};
               coords[i] = new_point_i;
             },
           );

    let rawData = [|[|1, 2|], [|3, 4|], [|9, 4|]|];

    append(rawData);

    Js.log("coords after");

    Js.log(coords);
    coords before
    [ { x: 9, y: 7 }, { x: 2, y: 4 }, { x: 3, y: 8 } ]
     -------
    coords after
    [ { x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }, { x: 9, y: 4 } ]
```

### Update

The following code is updated syntax for @yawar's code in the gist in the comments above. His explanation there is worth reading.

```
type data_item = {
  symbol: string,
  next: bool,
};

/* Convenience function for making data items. */
let make_data_item = (symbol, next) => {symbol, next};

let process = (data: list(data_item)) => {
  /*
   We track the current symbol as well as the result list in the folding function.
   */
  let fold_func = ((current, result), {symbol, next}) =>
    if (next) {
      (symbol, [current, ...result]);
    } else {
      (current ++ symbol, result);
    };

  let (current, result) = List.fold_left(fold_func, ("", []), data);
  /*
   We need to reverse the result list because `[el, ...els]` above actually
   builds it up in the _opposite_ order to the original input list.
   */
  (current, List.rev(result));
};

let result =
  process([
    make_data_item("a", false),
    make_data_item("b", false),
    make_data_item("c", true),
    make_data_item("d", false),
  ]);
/* result = ("cd", ["ab"]) */
```